# under what circumstances will git replacements be pushed/pulled

Tags: git

I need to make some local tweaks to history to make merges go more smoothly, traditionally the tool for doing this is grafts, however git is yelling at me that grafts are deprecated and will be removed in a future release and that I should use git-replace instead.

However there is something that is concerning me, https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint says

> As of Git 1.6.5, the more flexible git replace has been added, which allows you to replace any object with any other object, **and tracks the associations via refs which can be pushed and pulled between repos.**

However the git-replace man page makes no mention of push or pull.

under what circumstances will replacements be pushed or pulled, and what if any steps do I need to take to ensure that my replacements stay local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really two or three parts, depending on how you want to subdivide them:

- How replacements work via the `refs/replace/` namespace
- How refs can be transferred
- How refs are transferred by default

I'll repeat this sentence from the bottom of the long section here, before launching into the long answer:

> You can either add `refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*`—perhaps with an additional leading `+`—to your `remote.origin.fetch` lines, to get replacements fetched by default, or do a one-time command-line fetch with a refspec.

This is for `git fetch` only.  You can do a one-time command-line `git push` of a newly created replacement ref to send the replacement "upstream" to `origin` or any other upstream repository.

#### Reference namespaces and how replacements work

A Git replacement object doesn't actually *replace* the other object, but rather sort of *augment* it.  That is, in Git, every object—commit, tree, blob, or annotated tag—has a unique hash ID.  The hash ID is the "true name" of the underlying object.<sup>1</sup>  Internally, Git starts with an object ID—or gets one from somewhere, anyway—and uses the OID to find the underlying object.

Meanwhile, *refs* or *references* are mostly<sup>2</sup> any string that (a) starts with `refs/` and (b) meets the constraints imposed by [`git check-ref-format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format).  The next word, with words being separated by slashes, in the `refs/namespace/and/more/text` string, defines the *namespace* of this ref.  If the word is `heads`, the ref lives in the *branch names* namespace.  If the word is `tags`, the ref lives in the *tags* namespace, and so on.

A valid-and-sensible replacement ref starts with `refs/replace/`.  This is the fixed part of a replacement ref.  The remainder of the ref—the variable part—is the hash ID (OID) of the original Git object.  So if you have a commit whose hash ID is `a12345678901234567899012345678990123456789` and you want to have a replacement ref *for that commit*, you'd create a ref with that string prefixed by `refs/replace`.

Now, each ref should itself contain one valid Git hash ID.  (Some refs, such as branch names, are constrained to contain only *commit* hash IDs.  Others, such as tags, may contain the hash ID of any valid Git object.)  A *replacement* should contain the valid hash ID of an object of the same type as the object whose name makes up the variable part of the replacement ref.  So in this case, with `refs/replace/a12345678901234567899012345678990123456789` replacing a commit, it should contain the hash ID of *some other* commit.

That *other* commit *is* the replacement for the original commit.  When Git is about to look up any object by hash ID, Git *can* first check to see if some `refs/replace/*` ref exists with that OID as its name's variable part.  If so, that bit of Git code will instead look up the object whose hash ID is stored in the replacement ref.  In other words, there's code that resembles:

```
lookup(oid: string, allow_replacements: bool): internalObject {
    replacer = "refs/replace/" + oid
    if allow_replacements and exists_as_ref(replacer) {
        oid = read_ref(replacer)
    }
    return lookup_noreplace(oid)
}
```

(where `lookup_noreplace` is what we might think of when we think about `lookup`: it finds the actual object and returns some sort of handle for it).

Hence, replacements work by the existence of references (or refs) whose name is in the `refs/replace/` namespace.  Git works along more or less as normal, then at the last moment, veers off and fetches the replacement object instead of the original object.  You can force Git *not* to do this (`git --no-replace-objects ...`), and various commands such as `git fsck` and `git gc` internally avoid doing this as appropriate for correctness, but most Git commands do allow replacements.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is going to get ... interesting when the Great Hash Function Changeover happens.

<sup>2</sup>Special names like `HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on are sometimes treated as references, and sometimes not.  Obviously these do not start with `refs/`.

---

#### `git fetch` and `git push` transfer objects and set refs

Both `git fetch` and `git push` work by having one Git call up another Git.  Each Git has *its own* references, private to each Git.  They can *share* objects, by making copies of each other's objects; they will use the same OIDs for the same objects.  (See footnote 1 again.)

The protocol details differ slightly for fetch and push, but in general, the sender kicks the whole thing off by offering up some name(s) and OID(s): one OID per name, since this is how refs work.  The receiver can pick over the names and OIDs if desired.  In general, the receiver looks at one or both, depending on the situation.  If the receiving Git wants the underlying object, it says so.  If the receiving Git already has that object, it says so.  If the receiving Git wants an object, and the object is of some type that refers to additional objects—not a blob object, in other words—the sender should then offer the referred-to objects as well.<sup>3</sup>  In this way, the sender and receiver can agree on a minimal subset of objects that the sender must send.  The sender then builds a so-called *thin pack:*<sup>4</sup> you'll see "delta compressing" messages here.  The receiver collects it and fixes it up or takes the objects out of it as needed, and puts the resulting pack and/or objects into its repository.

Now that the receiver has the necessary objects, such as new commits with new files / content, the receiver needs to set some *names* to remember these objects.  This is where refs return to the picture.

If the receiver is a Git running `git fetch`, normally, this receiver sets *remote-tracking names*, such as `refs/remotes/origin/master`, to the same hash ID as the *branch names* it got from the sender.  The receiver may or may not take all tags or some tags, using rather complicated rules.  The receiver *ignores* all the other refs, including the `refs/replace/` ones.

If the sender is a Git running `git push`, whoever runs `git push` chooses which names to send.  The `git push` syntax allows the sender to choose an arbitrary name on the receiver; it's up to the receiver to accept or reject this name.  The default is to use the *same* name, and to push either the current branch, or some set of branches, depending on Git vintage and `push.default` settings.

If you, as the user of the computer, are running `git fetch` or `git push` yourself, *you* can supply all of the refs involved on both sides of the operation here, using what Git calls *refspecs*.

#### Using and setting refspecs

The full form of a refspec is:

- an optional leading plus sign `+`,
- a *source* ref,
- a colon `:`, and
- a *destination* ref.

The leading plus sign sets the *force flag* for this particular refspec: it asks whichever Git is receiving to set its (destination) ref even if this would violate the usual rules for this ref, whatever those usual rules may be.  Using `git fetch --force` or `git push --force` sets this same flag on every refspec even if it's not there in the refspec itself.

The *source* ref is the ref that the sender uses to find the OID to send.  The *destination* ref is the name the receiver uses.  If you're running `git fetch`, you're setting your own Git's receive-side name; if you're running `git push`, you're setting the name your Git hands to their Git.

More precisely:

- When you run `git fetch`, they send you their names-and-OIDs at the start of the session, and your Git combs through those to find matching names you used on your command line refspecs, as sources.  Then your Git receives, and then your Git writes to your names, using the *destination* refs you gave on the command line, in your refspecs.
- When you run `git push`, you choose which OIDs to send to their Git using the source names in the refspecs you give, and you choose what names to give *to* their Git using the destination names in the refspecs you give.

If you *don't* give refspecs, your Git computes some default ones.  Again, this varies for `git fetch` and `git push`:

- With `git fetch`, your Git looks up the *remote* name you used, such as `origin`.  Under this remote, there should be one or more settings for `remote.remote.fetch`  The (single) standard setting for `origin` is:

  ```
   remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  ```

This refspec is *why* their branch names become your remote-tracking names.

- With `git push`, the default refspec is based on `push.default`.  The default *value* of `push.default` is different in Git versions predating 2.0, where it defaults to `matching`, than in 2.0+, where it defaults to `simple`.  With `current` or `simple`, the refspec itself is `name:name` where *`name`* is the current branch name.  However, `simple` first checks that *`name`* has an *upstream* set.  If not, the push operation fails.  Otherwise, it checks that the upstream name is *the same* as the branch name.  If not, the push operation fails.

Note that none of these built in defaults ever match `refs/replace/*`.  However:

- When fetching to a mirror clone (a fetch mirror), the default refspec is instead:

  ```
   +refs/*:refs/*
  ```

This *does* match `refs/replace/*`, so replacement objects get copied.  Their ref names are unchanged, so they act as replacements in the usual way.

- When using a push mirror—these are specialized and even rarer than fetch mirrors—you would also push with `refs/*:refs/*` (perhaps with a leading `+`).  So this would also push replacement objects, maintaining their replacement-ness.

You can either add `refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*`—perhaps with an additional leading `+`—to your `remote.origin.fetch` lines, to get replacements fetched by default, or do a one-time command-line fetch with a refspec.

---

<sup>3</sup>For practical reasons, there are a bunch of short-cuts taken here with *tree* objects, so that the full graph analysis isn't done in most cases.  This usually leads to better performance but can result in a sender over-sending.  If Git used the obvious graph walk all the way down, Git could do a more perfect job here, at the expensive of exchanging a lot more OIDs in the slower initial offer/have/want style phase.  That's usually not a good tradeoff, which is why the short-cuts are used.  But in principle it works like this, at least.

<sup>4</sup>A *thin pack* is one that is delta-compressed against objects that are not in the pack itself.  The sender knows which commits (and thus which blob objects, i.e., file contents) the receiver has, at this point, so the sender can delta-compress to-be-sent objects against those objects that the receiver already has, without sending those objects.  That's a "thin pack".

Comment: wow, this is a great answer :D fearlessly diving into details

Answer (score 1):

I also posted this question on the git mailing list and got an answer there. It's a bit long to quote in full, but the gist of it is that replace references are local-only by default and special steps need to be taken to share them.

https://marc.info/?l=git&m=157893765418386&w=2